# Magento tax issue

Tags: tax

I was working on a new magento shop but im having issues configuring tax.

I have congured that the admin fills in prices including tax. Also the view settings are configured showing including tax.

I fill in 10 euro as normal price in the admin. I leave special or group / tier price alone. But on the front-end it shows the total price is (10 * 1.21) 12,1 euro.

Product price config back-end:

Product front-end:

Tax settings: 
[image]
[image]

I removed all external modules and theme's. The product i use in the screenshot is created without external modules.

If i echo

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('3');
echo $product->getPrice();
echo "_______________ <br>";
echo $product->getData('price');
```

It will echo the right price of the product, including tax which is 10.

I'm getting really desperate.. what am i doing wrong?

Magento Community 1.9.2.4

Comment: Product backend: https://i.imgur.com/u35rjQh.png
Product frontend: https://i.imgur.com/hUlCTVE.png

Comment: Can you give more information please. Can you upload a screenshot of the "Tax Rates", the "Tax rule" for your store and also what the default customer group is for your store.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below extra information.

Tax rates and rules: https://i.imgur.com/1MBxYhe.png

Customer groups: https://i.imgur.com/RT9cRtm.png

The default group is General.

Comment: I noticed that shipping costs have the exact same issue. I filled in 6,95 euro including tax for flat rate shipment. On the front-end the shipping costs are 8,41 euro.

Comment: Well the shipping rate is charging 21% VAT. Can you reindex your site and clear the cache and see what price is now showing for the product? If its still the same can you send me a screenshot of the edit page of the tax rule which is charging 21% and leave me know if there are other other tax rules under Catalog -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to enable cross border trading! Had the same problem and this setting solved it for me! Go to: System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Settings > "Set Enable Cross Border Trade to Yes"

Comment: Apparently 1.9.1.0 and the versions later  needs Cross border trade to be set to "Yes" for the price to shown correctly.